# Amazon S3 HEAD request returns an empty response instead of 404 for a non-existent object

Tags: c++, http, amazon-s3, boost-asio

I'm writing an Amazon S3 client library in C++ using `boost::asio` and composing `HEAD` and `GET` requests to query and download files.  Everything works fine until I send a `HEAD` request for an object that doesn't exist in my bucket.  A `GET` request for a non-existent object returns polite response headers with a 404 status code (as expected!) but a `HEAD` request for the same object returns absolutely nothing!  (I discovered this when my code threw an exception trying to read the headers from the response and there was nothing there to read.)

I'm following the documentation and various examples, including this one...

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetMetaOfObjVersion.html
```

My request looks something like this...

```
HEAD /does_not_exist.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: my_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: Wed, 30 Oct 2013 22:32:00 GMT
Authorization: AWS MY_KEY:...ETC...
Connection: close
```

The strangest thing is that everything works - both `HEAD` and `GET` requests - for valid files, and `GET` works for non-existent files (correctly returns headers reporting an error code), but I get absolutely no response (0 bytes!) to a `HEAD` request for a non-existent file.  I haven't found *anybody* on the web reporting any similar issues.  Am I the only one?

---- UPDATE ----

I've found that when my code executes *outside my office firewall*, everything behaves correctly: the `HEAD` request for the non-existent file returns nice HTTP headers indicating a 404 result.  Now to investigate what my firewall is doing to me... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a firewall, check your settings. It is quite possible that your firewall is filtering out certain responses from amazon.

Answer (score -1):

According to [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) para 9.4:
"The `HEAD method` is identical to `GET` except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a `HEAD` request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a `GET`request."

So the response to a `HEAD` request MUST NOT contain a message body, whilst the  header MAY contain a non-zero Content-Length and your code should NOT throw an exception under this circumstance.

`HEAD` is considered a "Look Before You Leap" request. It's purpose is to allow your client to determine whether it can receive the body of a GET request *before* it sends it.

Comment: I fully understand that I should expect no "message-body" from a HEAD request.  The problem is that I am getting *nothing* in response - no headers or any data whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry, I read "no response (0 bytes!)" as meaning an empty body, not "*nothing* in response".